# Why can't I push to these arrays? Is it because of Promises somehow?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, promise

I am really struggling to figure out why I can't just do `listOfPlanets.push(planetObj)` I assume it has something to do with promises? Some explanation would be appreciated.

requestp is included. It takes requests, and returns them inside promises.

```
function(req, res){
    var planetPromise = requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets');
    var listOfPlanets = [];
    planetPromise.then(function(planets){
        planets.results.forEach(function(planet){
            var residentPromises = new Array();
            if(planet.residents)
                planet.residents.forEach(function(person){
                    residentPromises.push(requestp(person));
                });
                var planetInhabitants = []
                var planetObj = {};
            Promise.all(residentPromises).then(function(people){

                people.forEach(function(p){
                    planetInhabitants.push(p.name.slice(0));
                })


                planetObj[planet.name] = planetInhabitants;//this works
                listOfPlanets.push(planetObj);//this does not

            }).then(function(){
                console.log("Out of the resident Promise stuff...")
            }).catch(function(err){
                return res.status(400).json({ "err": err })
            })

        })// forEach
        return res.json(listOfPlanets);
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("Out of the planet Promise stuff...")
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        return res.status(400).json({ "err": err })
    })
}
```

As it stands, I am having trouble pushing objects onto listOfPlanets, I try, but it seems that nothing is being added.

I want to get an array of objects where the planet names are the key, and the array of it's residents as the value.

Comment: Is that a typo? In the code section `listOfPlanets.push()` pushes nothing

Comment: Please don't just say "I can't do something" and be more specific, like what happens when you do this.

Comment: Sorry, edited to fix ```.push``` problem.

Answer (score 1):

It worked, you're just looking at the array too early. When you do the array push inside a `promise.then` block, it'll add the item after that promise executes, but you're not waiting for that when you're returning the array. You should instead return the promise that will actually include the modified array:

```
retPromise = Promise.all....
return retPromise;
```

Comment: It starts on the point, but the proposed solution there's nothing to do about it.

Comment: I am using the native node promises.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, kinda.

Here, I simplified (but didn't test) the code

```
function(req, res){
  return requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
    .then(function(planets) {
        return Promise.all(planets.results.flatMap(function(planet) {
          return planet.residents.map(function(person) {
            return requestp(person);
          })
        }));
    })
    .then(function(people){
      return res.json(people.map(function(p){
        return p.name;
      })
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      return res.status(400).json({ "err": err })
    });
}
```

Use `.map()` instead of the `forEach/push` thing you are fumbling with.  (Also, I assumed you have a `.flatMap()`.)

Perhaps the working version will illustrate yBot's point about only using the argument to a `then` in the context of the `then` itself.

Incidentally, here is the thing with ECMA-6 fat-arrow notation:

```
(req, res) => 
  requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
  .then(planets =>
    Promise.all(planets.results.flatMap(planet =>
                        planet.residents.map(requestp))))
  .then(people => res.json(people.map(p => p.name)))
  .catch(err = res.status(400).json({ "err": err }))
```

Even less boilerplate.

**Edit:** to give it the shape the OP is looking for (using the `_.object()` function from Underscore.js)

```
(req, res) => 
  requestp('https://swapi.co/api/planets')
  .then(planets =>
    Promise.all(planets.results.map(planet =>
                    planet.residents.map(requestp)
                    .then(people => [planet.name,
                                     people.map(p => p.name)]
                    ))))
  .then(listing => res.json(_.object(list)))
  .catch(err = res.status(400).json({ "err": err }))
```

Comment: How can you assume `flatMap` exists there?

Comment: This just returns all residents. I edited my post to say what I am trying to get, which is an array of objects, where the planet name is the key, and the array of its residents is the the value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Build a list of promise to each planet (planet$)
2. For each planet, build a list of promises to every person (person$)
3. Each planet$ promise resolves after all person$ complete
4. Wait for planet$ to resolve, then return a response

You have step 2, but steps 1 and 3 are missing.

```
const planet$ = planets.map(planet => getPeopleOfPlanet(planet))  // steps 1, 3
Promise.all(planet$)
  .then(list => res.json(list))  // step 4
```

`getPeopleOfPlanet(planet)` is the bulk of your code above. Use smaller functions as it is easier to follow.

Comment: All the planets are returned in a single call, I don't think I want to make an array of promises for them.

Comment: The planets, ay. You'll need a list of promises for each planet, one for each planet's residents. You need a list so you can deliver the final response.

Comment: That sounds confusing. "You'll need a list of promises for each planet, one for each planet's residents." Which one of these these is it? or is it both? Need a list of promises for each planet AND each person?

Comment: For each planet, a list of promises to residents. This is a promise itself (Promise.all([...])). Then you'll have a list of promises for planets with residents resolved.

Comment: I am confused about how to go about this if all the planets is a single call.

Comment: That's the missing part of your original code. You have a Promise.all() for the residents of a single planet. You need another list of promises, because to proceed with `res.json()` you need to wait for the residents of every planet to resolve. Forget about the initial single call to obtain the planets, this is okay already. The structure in my sample code above should work, have a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129695/discussion-between-bwighthunter-and-andre-werlang).